# How to know all records are inserted one which record in not inserted in batch insertion

Tags: java, jdbc

I am inserting multiple student list as code given below

```
int count = 0;
for (Student st :StudentList) {
    ps.setString(1, l.getId());
    ps.setString(2, l.getName());
    ps.setString(3, l.getRollNo());
    ps.addBatch();
    if (++count % 100 == 0) {
        ps.executeBatch();
    }
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

How can I know that all records inserted successfully. If not which record from list is/are not inserted.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDocs for [`Statement#executeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can easily be obtained by reading the [JavaDocs for `Statement#executeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeBatch()` method returns an array (`int[]`) of update counts containing one element for each command in the batch. So, `array[i] <= 0` means *i* th command has no affect on the database. If command *i* is an INSERT query, then this means it is not inserted.

For more detail about the content of the this array, you can look at the Javadoc of [executeBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()).

Answer (score 0):

This is from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) of executeBatch:

> The int elements of the array that is returned are ordered to
> correspond to the commands in the batch, which are ordered according
> to the order in which they were added to the batch.
>
> The elements in
> the array returned by the method executeBatch may be one of the
> following:
>
> A number greater than or equal to zero -- indicates that
> the command was processed successfully and is an update count giving
> the number of rows in the database that were affected by the command's
> execution